# File name encoding in firebase cloud

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database

I have few files which has icelandic characters in it.

However when I use getDownloadURL to get the url of the file by using it's fileaname or storage location, It's simply returning file not found. But both the file path and file name is correct.

So, it clearly seems like some encoding issue.

I'm using expo react native now.

[image]

I need to get the file URL by using it's file name with general encoding.

Comment: Are you sure that one of those two document IDs doesn't contain whitespace at the end?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `encodeURIComponent` function to URI encode the file name.

Here's an example:

```js
const fileName = 'Íslenska-filanafn.txt';
const encodedFileName = encodeURIComponent(fileName);
const downloadUrl = await storage().ref(encodedFileName).getDownloadURL();
```